# Graphic Not Appearing on CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, graphics, cardlayout

I'm building a GUI that uses a CardLayout to switch between screens. I want one of the screens to have a graphic on it. I've successfully been able to put a rectangle onto a panel with a GridLayout, and put that panel onto a main panel, and a rectangle is clearly visible. However, when I to put that panel onto a CardLayout Panel, the rectangle is nowhere to be seen. Is there something different that needs to be done when adding graphics to a CardLayout panel?

The Main Class

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    public Window() {
        // Main Panel Configuration
        Container panel = this.getContentPane();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setSize(1000,1000);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        // GridBag Constraints
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        // Button Tabs
        JButton button1 = new JButton("button 1");
        panel.add(button1, gbc);

        JButton button2 = new JButton("button 2");
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(button2, gbc);

        // Panels for CardLayout
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        // Set Layout of Panels
        panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        // Set Dimensions of Panels
        panel1.setSize(new Dimension(900, 500));
        panel2.setSize(new Dimension(900, 500));

        // Labels for panels
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("label 1");
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        panel1.add(label1, gbc);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("label 2");
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        panel2.add(label2, gbc);

        // TextFields for Panels
        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField();
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        panel1.add(textField1, gbc);

        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField();
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        panel2.add(textField2, gbc);


        // Add Graphic to panel1
        JPanel drawingPanel = new JPanel();
        DrawingComponent dc = new DrawingComponent();
        dc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        drawingPanel.add(dc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        panel1.add(drawingPanel,gbc);


        // Set TextField Dimensions
        textField1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 20));
        textField2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 20));

        // CardLayout Panel for Entry Fields and Labels
        JPanel cardLayoutPanel = new JPanel();
        CardLayout c1 = new CardLayout();
        cardLayoutPanel.setLayout(c1);
        cardLayoutPanel.setSize(new Dimension(900, 600));

        // Add Panels to CardLayout Panel
        cardLayoutPanel.add("panel1",panel1);
        cardLayoutPanel.add("panel2", panel2);

        // Which panel to show First
        c1.show(cardLayoutPanel, "panel1");

        // Add CardLayout Panel to Main Panel
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        panel.add(cardLayoutPanel, gbc);


        // Action Listeners Changing Between Tabs
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                c1.show(cardLayoutPanel, "panel1");
            }
        });


        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                c1.show(cardLayoutPanel, "panel2");
            }
        });

        setSize(800,600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Window window = new Window();

    }
}
```

The Drawing Component Class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class DrawingComponent extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(400, 400, 50, 50);
        g2.draw(rect1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first line of code in a paintComponent method must be `super.paintComponent(g)`.  Without that, you will get unpredictable behavior.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing - Lightweight Components](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#lw).  Also, you are drawing the rectangle at coordinates (400,400), but you are forcing your DrawingComponent’s size to 100×100, which means the rectangle is drawn in a place where it can’t be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you are drawing outside the bounds of your component.  Drawing a rectangle at (400, 400) will result in nothing being seen, when the component itself is forced to have a size of 100×100.

Another problem is that you are trying to explicitly set the sizes of your components and your window.  But the window is not big enough for those sizes.  When GridBagLayout is unable to accommodate the preferred sizes of its children, it “gives up” and sets everything to its minimum size.  Since DrawingComponent doesn’t define a minimum size, it reverts to having zero width and zero height.  (Your use of fill=HORIZONTAL forces it to be as wide as its cell, but the height is still zero.)

It is not correct to set all those sizes.  There is almost never a valid reason to call setSize or setPreferredSize.

For a JTextField, you need to set its size using its [setColumns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setColumns%28int%29) method.

The DrawingComponent class should know what size it wants to be, and it should return that size by overriding its own getPreferredSize method.  Obviously it has to be large enough to accommodate its own painting:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(500, 500);
}
```

For panels and windows, do not set the size at all.  They will all be big enough to accommodate their child components, if you build the entire window and then call [pack()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) on it.

Again, there should be *no* calls to setSize or setPreferredSize in your code.  You don’t need them.

Answer (score 2):

In this part:

```
JPanel drawingPanel = new JPanel();
DrawingComponent dc = new DrawingComponent();
dc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
drawingPanel.add(dc);
```

You set the preferred size of your `DrawingComponent` to (100,100). Then, when you draw the component, you draw the rectacle in `Rectangle(400, 400, 50, 50)` using the constructor `Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)`.

Having said that, i think it is pretty obvious. Your component is 100x100 but you try to draw at the 400thx400th pixel which causes the rectangle to be drawn outside of the bounds of your component.

I do not know what the coords of the rectangle should be but if you want your component to be shown, change the rectangle to `Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);`

Also, VGR mentioned in comments (he got me :P) when you `override` `paintComponent` method, make sure you call `super.paintComponent()`.

Finally, start your application by using `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` method.

A sum of what i mean into code:

```
public static class DrawingComponent extends JComponent {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); // Should always start with super method.
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
            g2.draw(rect1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // All swing applications must run on their own thread named EDT (Event dispatch thread)
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Window window = new Window();
        });
    }
```